# App is invisible if started from Task Scheduler without any user logged in

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, invisible, winlogon

Is there any way to have app visible even if it is started with "Run only if user logged on" unchecked?
I know that windows starts app from task invisible as there is no user logged into yet.
But when user logs in he would like to see that app instead of running in the background.

I would like to know the way to solve it. There must be a lot of people who faced this problem before.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for the app in the Windows Task Manager? Does the invisible app appear when you click "Show processes from all users" in Task Manager?

Comment: This is pretty much the point of Task Scheduler.  Not otherwise anything you can do about it, it is running on another desktop that you can't switch to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by tweaking autologon in Windows Registry (WinXP):
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

DefaultUsername and DefaultPassword. That is all what I needed. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like your application was not architectured correctly for the operating system being used.

This application sounds like it really should be running as a Windows Service, and then there should be a user-level application that can be used to manage it, as appropriate.

Running desktop-UI software without a valid desktop session is a bad idea, the fact that Windows lets you schedule just such a thing notwithstanding. But that you further want to go beyond the best-practices here to have the software "sometimes" be accessible strongly begs, in my opinion, for the architecture I noted above.