# How to make scheduled process run as the current user?

Tags: c++, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I schedule my application in the task scheduler using the ITask class incorporated with the winapi.

I have this piece of code: `dwTask->SetAccountInformation(L"", NULL);`

The first parameter requires the username of the user to run the task.

By setting it to blank it runs the task as a NTAUTHORITY/SYSTEM service and therefore I run into spikes in the system where when I run commands in that task it doesnt appear on the screen (I want to fix this, as I'd like to keep NTAUTHORITY/SYSTEM privileges with my application -> see my last question: [Task Scheduler WorkItem Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535075/task-scheduler-workitem-not-running/26535275?noredirect=1#comment41701133_26535275))

The question for this post is; How can I set the first parameter to the current user that is logged in? I tried to use `GetUserName` but the first parameter is a WIDE CHAR array data type. I tried to use `GetUserNameW` but the program still failed to compile due to unknown errors. Has anyone been able to set their scheduled task as the current user? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Okay! I added the `GetUserNameW` as suggested into my code. Then I linked it to the first parameter of `SetAccountInformation`. There are no errors compile time. After I run the program by double clicking it, it doesnt add the process as a task. Clearly it didn't work. Here is the code that I am using...

```
static bool AddProcessAsTask()
{
LPWSTR uname=L"";
DWORD size = 1024;

ITask *pITask;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
LPCWSTR pwszTaskName;
ITaskScheduler *pITS;
LPCWSTR pwszApplicationName;

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance
    (
        CLSID_CTaskScheduler,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskScheduler,
        (void **) &pITS
    );

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}

pwszTaskName = L"AV_Updater Watchdog";

hr = pITS->NewWorkItem
(
    pwszTaskName,
    CLSID_CTask,
    IID_ITask,
    (IUnknown**)&pITask
);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    CoUninitialize();
    return FALSE;
}

pwszApplicationName = L"C:\\Windows\\watchdog.exe";

hr = pITask->SetApplicationName(pwszApplicationName);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    pITS->Release();
    pITask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return FALSE;
}   

GetUserNameW(uname, &size);

pITask->SetAccountInformation(uname, NULL);

pITask->SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON);

pITS->AddWorkItem(pwszTaskName, pITask);
pITS->Release();

hr = pITask->Run();

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    pITask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return FALSE;
}

pITask->Release();
CoUninitialize();

return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Link to last question doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome, and please edit your question into a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That means providing the shortest amount of code that produces your problem...as well as pastes of the exact error message you get.  In this case, your problem seems to actually be "how do I call GetUserName" and perhaps "what is a wide character and how do I use it".  See [this answer on GetUserName](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17972581/211160) but also [warnings about TCHAR in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002494/211160).

Comment: added question in response

Comment: Your question seems to be "How to get the username of the logged in user?", and the answer is `GetUserName`. If you explain what these "unknown errors" are then we can help you.

Comment: Okay, so how would you use `GetUserNameW` with `SetAccountInformation()` of the `ITask` class? I think this is my question.

Comment: Use `GetUserName` to get the user name in a buffer, then pass the buffer to `SetAccountInformation`...